# Why IE (not Chrome and FF) add attributes to html node?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, formatting

Here is my issue only with IE:
I have a < li> node, coded like that in my HTML page:

```
<li id="3" class="tree_item_droppable ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
<span class="ui-droppable">Node name</span>
</li>
```

When I do a firebug on FF, I have exactly the same html node.
But, when I go on IE, it gives me the following:

```
<LI style="POSITION: relative" id=3 class="tree_item_droppable ui-draggable" unselectable="on" sizcache="0" sizset="15" jQuery1375462474765="27"><SPAN class=ui-droppable jQuery1375462474765="14">Node name</SPAN></LI>
```

I don't understand why it's formatted like that...

Is there a way, in IE, to have exactly the original formatting?

Thanks guys!

Comment: When asking questions about IE, always specify the version number. When you say "go on IE, it gives me the following" what *exactly* do you mean? Where do you see unexpected values? The F12 Tools?

Comment: I copied and pasted your HTML into a file locally and opened it in IE 10.  It's formatted exactly the same way as the original.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must have some JS/jQuery somewhere altering that node/element differently for IE than it would for the other browsers.

Based on the name of the classes it looks like jQuery UI is the culprit and assigns things differently when using IE vs. the other browsers.

Essentially IE is just doing what it is instructed to do by jQuery UI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I don't know how to troubleshoot that... I'm going to remove all references one by one and see how it goes...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your comments guys, I found out the source of my issue.

I have commented out the following and now I'm good :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

It works fine now in IE 9 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

I need to find a way to keep the .js script and avoid the "wrong" formatting in IE9.

Is there an option to set in the page html to avoid jquery to change the formatting?
I'm using jquery-1.7.2.js.

Just to sum up, please find below the output given to me when I save the html structure in the database:

## Chrome/FF

```
<li myid="1" class="tree_item_droppable ui-draggable">
<span class="defaultRootCauseDiv ui-droppable">samba</span>
<ul>
<li myid="1" class="tree_item_droppable ui-draggable" itemtype="rootCause">
<span class="nonTerminalCauseDiv ui-droppable">Non-Terminal Cause 1</span>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

## Internet Explorer (I just paste the first node)

```
<LI class="tree_item_droppable ui-draggable" unselectable="on" myid="1">
```

See how the formatting is messed up in IE (upper cases, additional attributes like "unselectable", "style")